Aws glue, db connection and data load based on timestamp

CDC -- Pipeline1 work is to load data (have list of tables) based on timestamp columns (creation_date, updation_date) from replica db (RDS) to S3 (landing_zone)

If I created rds connection on glue, would I need to use jdbc again as I told I need to pass tables and filter conditions, else need to load data and filter after loading.
connection_options = {
"connectionName": "myconnection",
"database": "dbname"
}
     for table in tables_list:
         connection_options['dbtable'] = table
         # how to pass query if we filter here only


         datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
             connection_type="postgresql",
             connection_options=connection_options
             )
          output_path = ""
          glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                 frame=datasource,
                 connection_type="s3",
                 connection_options={"path": output_path},
                 format="csv"
                 )



using jdbc i can able to pass query and get data but (the connection is configured with vpc, without vpn it can't connected)
Any solutions to filter or is it ok to filter on loading data.

Are the filter conditions based on the timestamp columns? Or there is further filtering after? You can create a spark dataframe and then run a following query to filter the data, lastly, convert the result back to dynamicframe.

In pipeline1 no transformations, as we are loading raw data based on timestamp columns (daily data), so at db level if we don't do filter (using query) we need to load all data and filter then, what do now?

Have you considered using glue job bookmarks? Here is the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html .In summary, you specify a primary key or a combination of keys to load data, when you pull the data from the db, it will only pull new data (based on the primary key). For example, if you have a table with 1 million rows today, it will pull the 1m rows, and tomorrow, it will only pull new rows, for example 10K. Let me know if this will be useful, and I can give you a more concrete example as a response.

need to load historical data also based on timestamp column, for future data we can work with bookmark. right now i am seeing only option is to load and add filter, I would have used jdbc option but connection is secured and its not allowing to connect. (throigh connection name only i need to work)
